# Unpack data from json columns in PostgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a table of attributes, one of them containing a json array of 11 numeric elements. I need to do some aggregation (nothing fancy, just averages, max/min stats, etc) on the data in the json array.

The generalized answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35178102/postgres-flatten-aggregated-key-value-pairs-from-a-jsonb-field/35179515#35179515) looks perfect for reformatting the data into a temporary view for quick queries. I changed jsonb_each to son_each (maybe this would work?) and return no error, but end up with a single column titled 'create_jsonb_pivot_view' with no data.

Here is the function:

```
create or replace function create_jsonb_pivot_view
    (table_name text, regular_columns text, json_column text)
returns void language plpgsql as $$
declare
    s text;
begin
    execute format ($fmt$
        select string_agg(format('%s->>''%s'' "%s"', key, key), ',')
        from (
            select distinct key
            from %s, json_each(%s)
            order by 1
            ) s;
        $fmt$, json_column, '%s', '%s', table_name, json_column)
    into s;
    execute format('
        drop view if exists %s_view;
        create view %s_view as 
        select %s, %s from %s', 
        table_name, table_name, regular_columns, s, table_name);
end $$;
```

And lastly the query that uses the function:

```
select create_jsonb_pivot_view('table', 'A, B, C, D', 'params')
```

I've never used functions in SQL before so this is some new territory for me. Perhaps there's a different and better way to achieve my goal all together?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind that actually worked – just took awhile to crunch the function. Was going to delete my post but if this is helpful for others I'll leave it!