# How to get data from Json to multiple column

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I want to choose which to extract and show it to each column, I want to have result like this query, but don't want to type this for every single thing like this

```
Select *,  
metrics::json ->> 'spend',
metrics::json ->> 'impressions',
metrics::json ->> 'clicks'
from t1
```

this show null, How to do if I choose to extract 'reach' and 'clicks',... to column but not all in the json?

```
select * 
from json_to_record('{"reach": 240, "spend": 3.34, "clicks": 10, "frequency": 1.0375}') 
as x(a int, b text, d text, e text)
```

I refer this [Stack over flow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39945308/how-to-get-a-json-object-as-column-in-postgresql)

[My DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=9f7ad5c4397e321fa51acef12455e680)

> EDIT: I have the main question is: how to choose which to extract
> without extract all like the 2nd query? The data have many rows, each row have json, can I do that with `Json_to_record` ?

Comment: You need `as x(reach int, spend numeric, clicks int, frequency numeric)`

Comment: I have the main question is: how to choose which to extract without extract all like the 2nd query? The data have many rows, each row have json, can I do that with `Json_to_record` ? @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: There is no way to do that without writing each column explicitly at one point or the other.

Comment: I think there is in my other question, " just specify the columns you want in the return structure"  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64219565/how-to-get-data-from-json-to-multiple-column-postgresql/64219994#64219994

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to select partial data from the JSON object, lets say 2 out of 4 keys, you can do so easily by omitting the rest of the keys from the *anonymous table* declaration. You need to use the JSON keys as column names.

```sql
select  *
from json_to_record('{"reach": 240, "spend": 3.34, "clicks": 10, "frequency": 1.0375}') 
as x(reach int,  clicks int)
```

This allows you to get the columns you need with little writing effort.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=dd39d912f6e696a8ace3670acf606959

Comment: I ask another question but more concise and it get answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64219565/how-to-get-data-from-json-to-multiple-column-postgresql/64219994#64219994

Comment: Please discuss more in this question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64219565/how-to-get-data-from-json-to-multiple-column-postgresql/64219994#64219994

Answer (score 1):

As a_horse_with_no_name said keep the **same** record names as these in the JSON and use aliases in the `select` list if needed.

```sql
select 
  reach as a, spend as b, clicks as c, frequency as d
from json_to_record('{"reach": 240, "spend": 3.34, "clicks": 10, "frequency": 1.0375}') 
as x(reach integer, spend numeric, clicks integer, frequency numeric);
```

Comment: his issue is that the scalar values come as null. You dont have to write column name twice.

Comment: No, they come just fine.

Comment: no they don't! check his fiddle. Its all null where there is a text scalar value. Also you see the columns are named just fine. No need to alias with same name again. ![image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/39703898/95109580-b0276e00-0734-11eb-9279-f5f943c253a1.png)

Comment: @TheFool: You have to "write column names twice" here to not get the `NULL`s. The [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE): "The function(s) ... `json[b]_to_record` ... extract(s) the values associated with keys **whose names match column names of the output row type**. Object fields that do not correspond to any output column name are ignored, and **output columns that do not match any object field will be filled with nulls**.". If you want other names than the keys, the query this answer shows is *at least* one solution.

Comment: I have the main question is: how to choose which to extract without extract all like the 2nd query? The data have many rows, each row have json, can I do that with `Json_to_record` ? @Stefanov.sm

Comment: I see, I got confused by the fiddle. Sorry about that.

Comment: @HaoHao: Query the data table `cross join lateral` the query in my answer with a where clause.

Comment: Please add DEMO @Stefanov.sm

Comment: the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64219565/how-to-get-data-from-json-to-multiple-column-postgresql/64219994#64219994