# Getting values from all JSON fields in postgres

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I need a SQL query where I can select all json keys. The following query let's me get all the keys to the JSON field. But I'm a bit at loss how I would go about making a query to also get all the values out too.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (key.*) key.*
FROM my_table,
jsonb_object_keys(my_table.json_field) as key
```

So the result of the above query would simply just be

```
key1 
key2
```

With the following query you would get a result similar to this

```
SELECT * FROM my_table

| id | json_field |
| -- | ---------- |
| 1  | '{"key1": "value1"}' |
| 2  | '{"key2": "value2"}' |
```

The result I'm looking for would be the following

```
| id | key1   | key2   |
| -- | -------| ------ | 
| 1  | value1 | null   |
| 2  | null   | value2 |
```

What makes it difficult is that I don't know the names of all keys which also may be a lot of keys for a single row.

Comment: Please show your schema structure and sample input/output. Or  at best  http://dbfiddle.uk demo.

Comment: I made an update that clarifies the structure better.

Comment: [Flatten aggregated key/value pairs from a JSONB field?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35179515/1995738)

Comment: @klin That looks like what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select distinct on (field_1, field_2) id, job_id, field_1, field_2
from
    my_table,
    jsonb_populate_recordset(json_field) jprs (field_1 int, field2 text)
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE

Comment: Thank you, I amended the question to better explain what I was after.