# recursively flatten a nested jsonb in postgres without unknown depth and unknown key fields

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

How can I recursively flatten a nested jsonb in postgres which I don't know the depth and the field at each depth? (see example below)

A postgressql query to do the flattening would be much apreciated

```
    {
       "xx": "",
       "xx": "",
       "form": "xxx",
       "type": "",
       "content_type": "xxx",
       "reported_date": ,
       "contact": {
           "imported_date": "",
           "name": "",
           "phone": "",
           "alternate_phone": "",
           "specialization": "",
           "type": "",
           "reported_date": ,
           "parent": {
               "_id": "xxx",
               "_rev": "xxx",
               "parent": "",
               "type": "xxx" 
               } 
        }
    }
```

I have searched in stack overflow but they only consider jsonb's which have a single depth and the keys are already known before

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Example setup:

```
create table my_table(id int, data jsonb);
insert into my_table values
(1,
$${
   "type": "a type",
   "form": "a form",
   "contact": {
       "name": "a name",
       "phone": "123-456-78",
       "type": "contact type",
       "parent": {
           "id": "444",
           "type": "parent type" 
           } 
    }
}$$);
```

The recursive query executes `jsonb_each()` for every json object found on any level. New key names contain full path from the root:

```
with recursive flat (id, key, value) as (
    select id, key, value
    from my_table,
    jsonb_each(data)
union
    select f.id, concat(f.key, '.', j.key), j.value
    from flat f,
    jsonb_each(f.value) j
    where jsonb_typeof(f.value) = 'object'
)
select id, jsonb_pretty(jsonb_object_agg(key, value)) as data
from flat
where jsonb_typeof(value) <> 'object'
group by id;

 id |                   data                   
----+------------------------------------------
  1 | {                                       +
    |     "form": "a form",                   +
    |     "type": "a type",                   +
    |     "contact.name": "a name",           +
    |     "contact.type": "contact type",     +
    |     "contact.phone": "123-456-78",      +
    |     "contact.parent.id": "444",         +
    |     "contact.parent.type": "parent type"+
    | }
(1 row)
```

If you want to get a flat view of this data you can use the function `create_jsonb_flat_view()` described in this answer [Flatten aggregated key/value pairs from a JSONB field?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35179515/1995738)

You need to create a table (or view) with flattened jsonb:

```
create table my_table_flat as 
-- create view my_table_flat as 
with recursive flat (id, key, value) as (
-- etc as above
-- but without jsonb_pretty()
```

Now you can use the function on the table:

```
select create_jsonb_flat_view('my_table_flat', 'id', 'data');

select * from my_table_flat_view;


 id | contact.name | contact.parent.id | contact.parent.type | contact.phone | contact.type |  form  |  type  
----+--------------+-------------------+---------------------+---------------+--------------+--------+--------
  1 | a name       | 444               | parent type         | 123-456-78    | contact type | a form | a type
(1 row)
```

The solution works in Postgres 9.5+, as it uses jsonb function introduced in this version. If your server version is older it is highly recommended to upgrade Postgres anyway to use jsonb efficiently.

Comment: what if the json has an array? this answer would not go into the array items
something like "contact.parent.phone.0" = "some number" and "contact.parent.phone.1" = "someother number"

Comment: @KaranRaina - It is possible to extend the above solution to support arrays, but in the context of generating table columns, this would be too complex to have any wider application. Also note that arrays would cause ambiguity. It is unclear whether `items.0` refers to an array element or an inner attribute `"0"` inside the object `"items"`.

Comment: @kiln, we can have `items.0` and `items[0]` for unambiguity

Answer (score 1):

Use function [`jsonb_unnest_recursive()`](https://github.com/rin-nas/postgresql-patterns-library/blob/master/functions/jsonb_unnest_recursive.sql) (link is to my GitHub)

Query:

```sql
select cardinality(path) as level,
       array_to_string(path, '.') as path,
       value
from jsonb_unnest_recursive($${
  "type": "a type",
  "form": "a form",
  "contact": {
    "name": "a name",
    "phone": "123-456-78",
    "type": "contact type",
    "numbers": [11,22,33],
    "parent": {
      "id": "444",
      "type": "parent type"
    }
  }
}$$::jsonb) as t;
```

Result:

| level | path | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | form | "a form" |
| 1 | type | "a type" |
| 2 | contact.name | "a name" |
| 2 | contact.type | "contact type" |
| 2 | contact.phone | "123-456-78" |
| 3 | contact.parent.id | "444" |
| 3 | contact.parent.type | "parent type" |
| 3 | contact.numbers.0 | 11 |
| 3 | contact.numbers.1 | 22 |
| 3 | contact.numbers.2 | 33 |