# Postgres recursive json limiting

Tags: postgresql, recursive-query, jsonb

Referencing [Postgresql jsonb traversal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46718006/postgresql-jsonb-traversal)

```
with recursive flat (id, timestamp, path, value) 
as (select id, timestamp, key, value 
    from trending_snapshot, jsonb_each(snapshot)
union select f.id, f.timestamp, j.key, j.value 
  from flat f, jsonb_each(f.value) j 
  where jsonb_typeof(f.value) = 'object' )
select timestamp, path, (value->>'value')::float AS value 
from flat 
where path like any(array['%Run01TubingPressure'])
limit 12;
```

Adding limit at the end does limit the return but it seems as if inside the with every record is checked.

Is it possible to limit inside a with union?

This query suffers terribly on large data sets.
I do see however that I can limit the timestamp range in the flat select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to limit the number of rows you should add `order by` and `limit` in the initial query, e.g.:

```
with recursive flat (id, timestamp, path, value) as (
    (select id, timestamp, key, value 
    from trending_snapshot, 
    jsonb_each(snapshot)
    order by id
    limit 12)
union all
    select f.id, f.timestamp, j.key, j.value 
    from flat f, 
    jsonb_each(f.value) j 
    where jsonb_typeof(f.value) = 'object' )
select timestamp, path, (value->>'value')::float AS value 
from flat 
where path like any(array['%Run01TubingPressure'])
```

or extra `where` clause (in the initial query) to filter rows according to a condition.

Comment: Interesting.  Ultimately we are trying to increase performance.  So far it is faster to just do a "select * from trending_snapshot limit X;" and then parse the json in a python script.

Comment: This may be a proper direction as recursion is not a strong point of RDBMS (in the context of performance).

Comment: Oh ok. Thank you!