# Extract and expand Postgres JSON column data into separate table

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

**There is a Postgres 9.6 table with these columns:**

```
targettable
------------------------------------------------------------------

id | name | jsonbdata                                      | class
------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | A    | {"a":"1","b":"2","c":[{"aa":"1"},{"bb":"2"}]}  | 1
2  | B    | {"a":"2","b":NULL,"c":[{"aa":"3"},{"bb":"2"}]} | 1
3  | C    | {"z":"1","y":"2"}                              | 2
```

`jsonbdata` holds JSON objects with different structures, but share identical structure within the same `class`.

**Question:**
I'd like to extract all `jsonbdata` rows matching a `class` into an empty new temp table with columns for each top level JSON key, and need some help structuring my query.

---

**Where I'm at now:**

```
create temp table testtable (id serial primary key);

with testrow as (select * from targettable where class = 1 limit 1)
select * from jsonb_populate_record(null::testtable, (select to_jsonb(jsonbdata) from testrow));
```

I think this might work if `testtable` had column names matching the JSON keys, but I'm unsure how to add table columns based on keys from a JSON object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the function `create_jsonb_flat_view()` described [in this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35179515/1995738)

Create a table (or a temporary table or a view) for a given class:

```
create table targettable_class_1 as
-- create temp table targettable_class_1 as
-- create view targettable_class_1 as
select *
from targettable
where class = 1;
```

and use the function to create a flat view:

```
select create_jsonb_flat_view('targettable_class_1', 'id, name', 'jsonbdata');

select *
from targettable_class_1_view;

 id | name | a | b |             c              
----+------+---+---+----------------------------
  1 | A    | 1 | 2 | [{"aa": "1"}, {"bb": "2"}]
  2 | B    | 2 |   | [{"aa": "3"}, {"bb": "2"}]
(2 rows)
```

Comment: This looks promising. I'll parse the function in that answer and report back. Thanks!

Comment: Function works as expected! The function seems to throw an error if a passed in key has a single quote though. Contrived example: {"Fruit's name":"Mango"} generates a syntax error.

Comment: @sheepgobeep - I've corrected the function, you can check it. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Aces! Much more elegant than the convoluted path I was going down.