# Creating columns from a enum type in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have an enumerated type on PostgreSQL, and I want to create a view that has a column for each enumerated value.

My use case is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35178102/postgres-flatten-aggregated-key-value-pairs-from-a-jsonb-field).  I have a jsonb column that I want to turn into a view with columns made up of the keys of the json blob.  The difference in my case is that the valid keys are defined in an enum rather than aggregated from the objects themselves.

The following SQL statement is essentially what I want to do, but doesn't work:

```
SELECT json_populate_record(null::activity_type_enum, activities) from some_table;
```

Is there a way to cast the enumerated type into what is expected by the first argument of `json_populate_record`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That needs some dynamic SQL.

Assuming all the columns in the view should have `text` type.

1. We get the enum members as an array with `enum_range()` and transform them into a set using `unnest()`.
2. To each enum member in the set we append `' text'` and use `string_agg()` to build a comma separated list of them. Like that, we get a column definition.
3. We build a `CREATE VIEW` statement selecting from the table lateral cross joining `json_to_record()` aliased with the column definition we built.
4. Execute the `CREATE VIEW` statement with `EXECUTE`.

Together we get the following `DO` block:

```
DO
$$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE '
CREATE VIEW some_view
AS
  SELECT x.*
         FROM some_table t
              CROSS JOIN LATERAL json_to_record(t.activities) x(' || (SELECT string_agg(un.m || ' text', ', ')
                                                                             FROM unnest(enum_range(NULL::activity_type_enum)) un(m)) || ');
';
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=c50394302506ae1071eabb1dbefabd39)

Replace `json_to_record()` with `jsonb_to_record()`, if the type of `activities` is `jsonb` rather than `json`.

If the enum changes however, the `DO` block has to be rerun, to have the view reflect the changes.

Comment: That's a more concise version of something I had come up with myself.  I was hoping to avoid dynamic SQL, but it sounds like it's not possible.  Thanks for the answer!