# Automatically Normalizing a Postgres JSON Column into a New Table

Tags: python, sql, pandas, postgresql, jsonb

I have a *very large* Postgres table with millions of rows. One of the columns is called `data` and is of type `JSONB` with nested JSON (but thankfully no sub-arrays). The "schema" for the JSON is mostly consistent, but has evolved a bit over time, gaining and losing new keys and nested keys.

I'd like a process by which I can normalize the column into a new table, and which is as simple a process as possible.

For example, if the table looked like:

```
id | data
---+----------------------------------------------
  1| {"hi": "mom", "age": 43}
  2| {"bye": "dad", "age": 41}
```

it should create and populate a new table such as

```
id | data.hi | data.age | data.bye
---+----------------------------------------------
  1|     mom |       43 | NULL
  2|    NULL |       41 |  dad
```

(Note: that the column names aren't crucial)

In theory, I could do the following:

1. Select the column into a Pandas DataFrame and run a [json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) on it
2. Infer the schema as the superset of the derived columns in step 1
3. Create a Postgres table with the schema of step 2 and insert ([to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) is an easy way to achieve this)

This doesn't seem too bad, but recall, the table is very large and we should assume that this cannot be done from a single DataFrame. If we try to do the next best thing -which is to batch the above steps- we'll run into the problem that the schema has changed slightly between batches.

Is there a better way to solve this problem then my approach? A "perfect" solution would be "pure SQL" and not involve any Python at all. But I'm not looking for perfection here. Just an automatic and robust process that doesn't require human intervention.

Comment: Read *Generalized solution* in [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35179515/1995738)

Comment: That's kind of amazing!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create a new table via the [CREATE TABLE AS](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-createtableas.html) statement.

```sql
CREATE TABLE newtable AS
SELECT 
  id, 
  (data->>'hi')::text AS data_hi,
  (data->>'bye')::text AS data_bye,
  (data->'age')::int AS data_age
FROM mytable
```

If the JSON structure is unknown, all keys and data types can be selected like this:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
  jsonb_object_keys(data) as col_name,
  jsonb_typeof(data->jsonb_object_keys(data)) as col_type
FROM mytable
```

Output:

```
col_name    col_type
--------------------
bye         string
hi          string
age         number
```

For a nested structure

```
id   data
---------
3    {"age": 33, "foo": {"bar": true}}
```

you can use a recursive query:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
  select
    jsonb_object_keys(data) as col_name,
    jsonb_object_keys(data) as col_path,
    jsonb_typeof(data->jsonb_object_keys(data)) as col_type,
    data
  from mytable
  union all
  select
    jsonb_object_keys(data->col_name) as col_name,
    col_path || '_' || jsonb_object_keys(data->col_name) as col_path, 
    jsonb_typeof(data->col_name->jsonb_object_keys(data->col_name)) as col_type,
    data->cte.col_name AS data
  from cte
  where col_type = 'object'
) 
SELECT distinct col_path AS col_name, col_type 
FROM cte
WHERE col_type <> 'object';
```

Output:

```
col_name    col_type
--------------------
age         number
foo_bar     boolean
```

Next, you need to build a list of columns for the `SELECT` clause based on this data for use in the `CREATE TABLE AS` statement, as shown above.

The following fiddle has a helper that generates the entire SQL:

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b7c782ce6f2b911c6f6b1503e7be122b)

Note that all numeric types, including fractional ones, will be designated as number type and require correction.

Comment: Thanks id'7238 for your answer. It shows how a `CREATE SELECT` can be used to populate the normalized table from the JSON column. However, in order to write the create statement, we needed to know the schema. I would like to have the SQL figure this out automatically. Perhaps [jsonb_populate_record](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-json.html#id-1.5.8.22.5.11.2.2.9.1.2.1) might be useful in this regard.

Comment: Even if we are able to tackle the above problem, `jsonb_populate_record` only looks at the top level of the JSON. In order to unwind the sub-jsons we would somehow need a recursive version.

Comment: If the JSON data structure is unknown, then you can try to get all the names of the keys and their data type (see [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=7c1cc3c70f7cfb4eb8960f00ca52a9e0)). But you will have to manually describe the list of columns in the SELECT clause based on this data and then execute the CREATE TABLE AS query, as described above. I don’t know how useful this will be in your case.

Comment: I’ll stew over that. Pretty spectacular SQL in that DB Fiddle!