# Create rows from part of column names

Tags: postgresql, dbt

### Source data

I am working on an ELT project to load data from CSV files into PostgreSQL where I will transform it. The CSV files have many columns that are consistent across files, but also contain activity columns that are inconsistent with names like `Date (05/19/2020)`, `Type (05/19/2020)`, etc.

In the loading script I am merging all of the columns with dates in the column name into one `jsonb` column so I don't have to constantly add new columns to the raw data table.

The resulting jsonb column in the raw data table looks like this:

| id | activity |
| --- | --- |
| 12345678 | {"Date (05/19/2020)": null, "Type (05/19/2020)": null, "Date (06/03/2020)": "06/01/2020", "Type (06/03/2020)": "E"} |
| 98765432 | {"Date (05/19/2020)": "05/18/2020", "Type (05/19/2020)": "B", "Date (10/23/2020)": "10/26/2020", "Type (10/23/2020)": "T"} |

### JSON to columns

Using the amazing `create_jsonb_flat_view` function from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35178102/flatten-aggregated-key-value-pairs-from-a-jsonb-field/35179515#35179515) I can convert the jsonb to columns like this:

| id | Date (05/19/2020) | Type (05/19/2020) | Date (06/03/2020) | Type (06/03/2020) | Type (10/23/2020 | Date (10/23/2020) | Type (10/23/2020) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10629465 | null | null | 06/01/2020 | E |  |  |  |
| 98765432 | 05/18/2020 | B |  |  | 10/26/2020 | T |  |

### Need to move part of column name to row

Now, this is where I'm stuck. I need to remove the portion of the column name that is the Activity Date (e.g. (05/19/2020)) and create a row for each `id` and `ActivityDate` with additional columns for `Date` and `Type` like this:

| id | ActivityDate | Date | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345678 | 05/19/2020 | null | null |
| 12345678 | 06/03/2020 | 06/01/2020 | E |
| 98765432 | 05/19/2020 | 05/18/2020 | B |
| 98765432 | 10/23/2020 | 10/26/2020 | T |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed your link to the `create_jsonb_flat_view` article yesterday and then forgot this question.  While I thank you for pointing me there, I think that mentioning it worked against you.

A more conventional approach using `regexp_replace()` works here.  I left the date values as strings, but you can convert them with `to_date()` if needed:

```
with parse as (
  select id, e.k, e.v,
         regexp_replace(e.k, '\s+\([0-9/]{10}\)', '') as k_no_date,
         regexp_replace(e.k, '^.+([0-9/]{10}).+', '\1') as k_date_only
    from rawinput
         cross join lateral jsonb_each_text(activity) as e(k, v)
)
select id,
       k_date_only as activity_date,
       min(v) filter (where k_no_date = 'Date') as date,
       min(v) filter (where k_no_date = 'Type') as type
  from parse 
 group by id, k_date_only;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=961809ebac1d63146f33060373a7a6c7)*

Answer (score 0):

@Mike-Organek's [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72928908/5162625) works beautifully!

However, I was curious if the `regexp_replace()` calls might be slowing the query down a bit and it seemed I could get the same results using a simpler function.

Since Mike gave me a great example to start with I modified it to split on the `space` between `Date` and `(05/19/2020)`.

For 20,000 rows, it went from taking an avg of 7 sec on my local machine to an avg of .9 sec.

Here is the resulting query:

```
 with parse as (
  select id, e.k, e.v,
         split_part(e.k, ' ', 1) as k_no_date,
         trim(split_part(e.k, ' ', 2),'()') as k_date_only
    from rawinput
         cross join lateral jsonb_each_text(activity) as e(k, v)
)
select id,
       k_date_only as activity_date,
       min(v) filter (where k_no_date = 'Date') as date,
       min(v) filter (where k_no_date = 'Type') as type
  from parse 
 group by id, k_date_only;
```